# Override toolbar back button action in ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, back-button, ionic4

in Ionic 3 can override  back button action by `navbar.backButtonClick = ()=>{}`

since navbar, navcontroller no longer exists in ionic 4

what is the similar why to override the `ion-back-button` back action

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code on your `AppComponent` class.

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {
    // You decide what happens 
});
```

Comment: isnt this is hardware backbutton? edit:previously in ionic3 for this was this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(fn)

Comment: Yes, this is `hardware back button`.

Comment: but the question is to override the toolbar back button icon action

Comment: This is the same for both the `software` and the `hardware` `back button`.

Comment: i tried for `software`  `back button`  did not trigger the callback

Comment: Then you need to raise an issue here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

My friend, this way it works.. android and ios hahaha

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>

        <ion-buttons slot="start" style="position: relative;">
            <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
            <div (click)="backButtonClick()" style="position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color: transparent;z-index: 1000;"></div>
        </ion-buttons>

    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: a useful hack for when you've had enough! Nice going Mario

Comment: Don't provide hack, this can change how ion-back-button displayed on various platforms

Comment: I do not like hacks either. this is temporary. Someone needs to solve this problem. developers need freedom.